# Exception when loading application context with spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have problem to use DI in spring. I have 3 classes which one of them is abstract. I have problem to add one service no another. I got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [sun.proxy.$Proxy14 implementing org.toursys.processor.service.Constants,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.toursys.processor.service.GameService] for property 'gameService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I am really desperate why it cannot convert please help

my app context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="repositoryContext.xml" />


    <bean id="abstractService" class="org.toursys.processor.service.AbstractService" abstract="true">
        <property name="tournamentAggregationDao" ref="tournamentAggregationDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="gameService" class="org.toursys.processor.service.GameService" parent="abstractService" />

    <bean id="groupService" class="org.toursys.processor.service.GroupService" parent="abstractService">
        <property name="gameService" ref="gameService" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractService implements Constants {

    protected TournamentAggregationDao tournamentAggregationDao;
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Required
    public void setTournamentAggregationDao(TournamentAggregationDao tournamentAggregationDao) {
        this.tournamentAggregationDao = tournamentAggregationDao;
    }
}
```

--

```
public class GameService extends AbstractService {


}
```

--

```
public class GroupService extends AbstractService {

    private GameService gameService;

    @Required
    public void setGameService(GameService gameService) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

ok get rid of this exception when I delete: "implements Constants" in my abstractService. Now it look like:

```
public abstract class AbstractService { ... }
```

but I have no idea which it cant implement interface where is just constants:

```
public interface Constants {

    int BEST_OF_GAMES = 9;

}
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224465/spring-use-of-proxies-in-spring-aop

Comment: Your `implements Constants` is anti-pattern.  Use `import static Constants.*;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the exception spring uses java proxies: `of type [sun.proxy.$Proxy14` .

A java proxy can only be created for interfaces - not for classes.

Change your code in this way:

```
 public interface GameService  {
 }

 public class GameServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements GameService {
 }
```

and your bean.xml to

```
<bean id="gameService" class="org.toursys.processor.service.GameServiceImpl" parent="abstractService" />
```