# Why spring can't find my bean?

Tags: java, spring

I created an interface and a class:

```
public interface UserService {
    List<User> listAll();
}

@Transactional
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
    private String tableName;
    public List<User> listAll() { someDao.listAllFromTable(tableName); }
    public void setTableName(String tableName) { this.tableName = tableName; }
}
```

Also in my application context xml file `context.xml`, I defined:

```
<bean id="userService" class="mypackage.DefaultUserService">
    <property name="tableName" value="myusers" />
</bean>
```

Then I want to test the `DefaultUserService`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:context-test.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "testTransactionManager")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DefaultUserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        userService.setTableName("mytesttable");
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // test with userService;
        userService.listAll();
    }
}
```

Notice it uses `context-test.xml`, which imported the original `context.xml`:

```
<import resource="classpath:context.xml"/>
```

Unfortunately, when the test starts, spring throws exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mypackage.UserServiceTest': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
private mypackage.DefaultUserService mypackage.userService

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [mypackage.DefaultUserService] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I'm not sure where is wrong, why spring can't find the bean `DefaultUserService` I defined?

Comment: The `<bean>` declaration you have is in `context-test.xml`?

Comment: Did you mean to type `public class DefaultUserService` in that first codeblock?

Comment: @Sotirios, see my updated question, I have that declaration.

Comment: @Dan, yes. Spring can't inject `DefaultUserService` bean for my test.

Comment: Are you building your app with Maven? Do you have a possibly empty file called `context.xml` in `/src/test/resources`?

Comment: You have `<context:annotation-config />` in your context.xml? And just curious but shouldn't there be a setter for `userService` in `UserServiceTest`?

Comment: @Dan If OP didn't, there wouldn't be `Could not autowire field:`. Injection with `@Autowired` doesn't require setters.

Comment: It's because `@Transactional` places the bean is behind jdk proxy http://stackoverflow.com/a/18875681/241986. You can try setting the table name with a property placeholder `@Value("${someprop}")`. Or create another interface that will have `setTableName` and the test will be referring to.. I'm not sure there are any neat solutions of the problem.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, you are right!! Many thanks to you. Could you make your comment as answer, and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) places the bean is behind a jdk proxy implementing `UserService` interface, after that the bean is only available as `UserService` and not `DefaultUserService`. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875681/241986.

You can try setting the table name with a property placeholder `@Value("${someprop}")` and define that property in test context, or create another interface that will expose `setTableName()`, and autowire that helper interface into the test case.

I'm not sure there are any easy solutions of the problem, I think this task can be subsumed under the problem of bean redefinition in Spring test-context framework
[Spring beans redefinition in unit test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565334/spring-beans-redefinition-in-unit-test-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the class `DefaultUserService` to the interface `UserService`

```
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    ....

}
```

Comment: It works, but I can't call 'setTableName(...)' to set my test table name, since `UserService` doesn't have such a method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the `getter` for your property `tableName` in your `implementing class`.Spring `IOC` container works on the `POJO` model