# whats is wrong with AOP using in Spring based project?

Tags: java, spring, aop

It seems that I searched for information from various sources over google to solve my problem, but I am still in trouble.
To clarify my problem I will give you as much information as I can.

I am using  NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 and Spring 3.1.1.

#### **What I have now:**

I created 6 classes and 1 xml file.

These classes are working fine (because these classes are based from book which I am currently reading).

I suppose something is wrong with my jar files (maybe somthing is wrong with versions compatibility or something (idk, i am new in this scope)).

**XML FILE:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        **http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">**

        <bean id="knight" class="castle.BraveKnight">
        <constructor-arg ref = "quest"/>

        </bean>

        <bean id="quest"
              class="castle.SlayedDragonQuest"/>      

        <bean id="mistreal"
              class="castle.Mistreal"/>
        <aop:config>
            <aop:aspect ref="mistreal">
                <aop:pointcut id="embark"
                    expression="execution(* *.embarkQuest(..))" />
                <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark"
                        method="singBeforeQuest"/>
                <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark"
                    method="signAfterQuest"/>


              </aop:aspect>
              </aop:config>

 </beans>
```

After compiling my code, I am getting this:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [knight.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

**It is obvious that classloader cannot find my aop class which is called Advice. But why?**

I added jars to my project like this:

[image]

**Did I miss something?** Can anyone give me some information. (I read related resources but result is the same).

Thank you

**EDITED:**

I added **aopalliance.jar file,** now I am getting this:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [knight.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate method [signAfterQuest] on bean [mistreal]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)

**It seems that one solution rises another problem. How can I fix it? 
P.s. I am not using a Marven. And also this is a mistake in my picture, i fixed it in my project, but it didn't change anything.**

**Mistreal class:**

```
    package castle;


public class Mistreal {

    public void singBeforeQuest(){
        System.out.println("Singing before quest");
    }

    public void singAfterQuest(){
        System.out.println("Singing after quest");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not focus on 2 different versions in SPRING-AOP jar files ( i deleted my 3.0.7), so now i Have only 3.0.0 version added to my project. Result is the same.

Comment: Show us your `Mistreal` class.

Comment: You simply have a typo, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need the `aopalliance` library which contains, among others, the `org.aopalliance.aop.Advice` class. You can get it for maven (or download the jar), [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance).

If you are using Maven, then `spring-aop` should bring it in, since [it is one of its dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/3.0.7.RELEASE). If not, you will have to download it (and anything else) and add it (them) manually to your classpath/build path.

As others have noted, use a single `spring-aop` jar.

You have a typo

```
<aop:after pointcut-ref="embark"
                method="signAfterQuest"/>
```

In the above pointcut, you use `signAfterQuest` but your method is called

```
public void singAfterQuest(){
    System.out.println("Singing after quest");
}
```

`singAfterQuest`. The hint is in the logs

```
Unable to locate method [signAfterQuest] on bean [mistreal] at
```

For the new error, Spring, by default, uses JDK proxies, but those only work on interfaces. You therefore cannot inject a Proxy into a variable of a `class` type. Instead you will need to use CGLIB proxies with this change to your XML configuration

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
```

This will also require you add CGLIB and related libraries to your classpath. More details in related answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224465/spring-use-of-proxies-in-spring-aop).

Comment: Omg, what a small mistake. I hate those little mistakes which are almost invisible to human eyes, thank you. After this i got:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: castle.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to castle.BraveKnight

Comment: @user You need to start helping yourself. See my edit for how to fix it.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because problem with AOP solved (I Guess), but now there is an exception above. Can you help me figure it out? After this i will go like a winner ^^

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have both:

`spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar` and `spring-aop-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar`

Is this intended? Maybe there is some sort of conflict.

Edit: as @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out, you need the aopalliance jar located [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.aopalliance&version=1.0.0). Maven is definitely a good resource for pulling in required dependencies, and easy to use. I would recommend looking into it.

Comment: Sorry for this, I fixed it and deleted one of these. I left only 3.0.0 version

Comment: I do not know how to use Marven, because today is my first day I am using Spring through Spring In Action book. And i faced with problem using AOP approach. And now, I spend over 3 hours for finding the problem.