# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spring.service.UserServiceImpl.addUser(Lspring/model/User;)V

Tags: java, spring

Im making spring security based web app, I made register form and got following error when I try to add new user:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spring.service.UserServiceImpl.addUser(Lspring/model/User;)V
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spring.service.UserServiceImpl.addUser(Lspring/model/User;)V
    at managedController.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 71 more
```

UserManagedBean.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package managedController;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import spring.model.Role;
import spring.model.User;
import spring.service.UserServiceImpl;

/**
 *
 * @author Krzysiek
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserServiceImpl}")
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    List<User> userList;

    private Integer id;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String passwordConfirm;

    public UserManagedBean() {
    }

    public String addUser() {
        try {
            if (!getPassword().equals(getPasswordConfirm())) {
                // throw new Exception("Passwords do not match!!");
            }
            User user = new User();
            user.setLogin(getLogin());
            user.setPassword(getPassword());
            Role role = new Role();
            role.setId(3);
            user.setRole(role);
            getUserServiceImpl().addUser(user);
            reset();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registration Success!", ""));
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Registration Failure, " + e.getMessage(), ""));
            return null;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    /**
     * Reset Fields
     */
    public void reset() {
        //this.setId(0);
        this.setLogin("");
        this.setPassword("");
        this.setPasswordConfirm("");
    }

    public UserServiceImpl getUserServiceImpl() {
        return userServiceImpl;
    }

    public void setUserServiceImpl(UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl) {
        this.userServiceImpl = userServiceImpl;
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Krzysiek
 */
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String login) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        Query query = openSession().createQuery("from User u where u.login = :login");
        query.setParameter("login", login);
        userList = query.list();
        if (userList.size() > 0) {
            return userList.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Krzysiek
 */
@Service("UserServiceImpl")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl;

    public UserServiceImpl() {  
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String login) {
        return userDAOImpl.getUser(login);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addUser(User user) {
        getUserDAOImpl().addUser(user);
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return getUserDAOImpl().getUsers();
    }

    public UserDAOImpl getUserDAOImpl() {
        return userDAOImpl;
    }

    public void setUserDAOImpl(UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl) {
        this.userDAOImpl = userDAOImpl;
    }

}
```

register.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-color: #6699CC;">

        <div style="">
            <div style="    right:45%;
                 bottom: 45%;
                 transform: translate (50%,50%);
                 position: absolute;
                 border-style: inset;
                 border-width: 4px;
                 border-color: azure;
                 background-color:white;
                 padding: 2em;">
                <h:form  id="registerFormId" prependId="false">
                    <div id="registerFieldsPnlId">
                        <div id="registerFieldUsrContId">
                            <h:outputText id="outTxtLoginId" value="Username: " name="outTxtLoginNm"></h:outputText>
                            <h:inputText id="login" required="true" value="#{userMB.login}" requiredMessage="Please enter username"></h:inputText>
                            <h:outputLabel id="outLblLoginId" for="login" name="outLblLoginNm"></h:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div id="registerFieldPassContId">
                            <h:outputText id="outTxtPasswordId" value="Password: " name="outTxtPasswordNm"></h:outputText>
                            <h:inputSecret id="password"  required="true" value="#{userMB.password}" requiredMessage="Please enter password" name="inTxtPasswordNm"></h:inputSecret>
                            <h:outputLabel id="outLblPasswordId" for="password" name="outLblPasswordNm"></h:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                            <div id="registerFieldPassContConfirmId">
                            <h:outputText id="outTxtPasswordConfirmId" value="Confirm Password: " name="outTxtPasswordConfirmNm"></h:outputText>
                            <h:inputSecret id="passwordConfirm"  required="true" value="#{userMB.password}" requiredMessage="Please confirm password" name="inTxtPasswordConfirmNm"></h:inputSecret>
                            <h:outputLabel id="outLblPasswordConfirmId" for="passwordConfirm" name="outLblPasswordConfirmNm"></h:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="registerBtnPanelId">
                        <h:commandButton id="addUser" value="register" action="#{userMB.addUser}"></h:commandButton>
                        <h:commandButton id="btnCancelId" value="Cancel" action="#{userMB.reset}"></h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h:messages></h:messages>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<!-- navigation-rule for register.xhtml -->
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/unsecure/register.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <!-- navigation-case for method login() -->
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{userMB.addUser}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/secure/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <!-- navigation-case for method login() -->
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{userMB.addUser}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/unsecure/register.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Thats everything that is related to User and register, I have no idea what error happens, I got the method, so why can't I register and got exception?

After I changed userServiceImpl to userService (interface) method is found but nullpointerexception is thrown:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at managedController.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 71 more
```

line 60 is:

```
getUserService().addUser(user);
```

Comment: No it isn't. You are using Spring Web Flow and that is handling the form submit. So it isn't the method of your managed bean that is called but the action you have specified in Spring Web Flow.

Comment: I am not sure how can I fix it?

Comment: I changed my register.xhtml form to form I am using to add customes and it still doesnt work, it works for adding customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programming against implementation classes instead against interfaces and you are using AOP (@Transactional) .. please try to 
reference other spring beans via their interfaces.

Otherwise you have to make sure that your application is configured to proxy classes using cglib ([Use of proxies in Spring AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224465/spring-use-of-proxies-in-spring-aop))

Comment: I changed it to interface
    `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserService}")
    UserService userService;`
method is found now but got error:      `Registration Failure, null`

without any exceptions in console

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserServiceImpl}")
UserService userService;
```

this was enough to make it works, thanks.

Comment: :-) cool .. you added a comment to my answer that you were getting null pointer exceptions after switching to interfaces ... how did you resolve that ?

Comment: That was my fault cause I changed MangedProperty to UserService instead UserServiceImpl so it was:

`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserService}")
UserService userService;`

instead of

`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserServiceImpl}")
UserService userService;`