# Mybatis - parameter mapping in QueryBuilder class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am fairly comfortable at using mybatis as an ORM tool.
But i am not able to understand how parameter mapping works in mybatis.

say i have a mybatis mapper interface defined that has a method to fetch the user details.

And I have my `Querybuilder` *class* defined, which has the select `query`.

```
public interface UserMapper {

    @SelectProvider(type = UserQueryBuilder.class, method = "getUserId")
    Long getUserId(@Param("first") String firstName, @Param("last") String lastName, @Param("location") String location);

}


public class UserQueryBuilder(){

    public String getUserId(String firstName, String lastName, String location) {
        return new SQL() {{
            SELECT("USER_TABLE.USER_ID");
            FROM("USER_TABLE");
            WHERE("USER_TABLE.FIRST_NAME" + " = #{first}");
            WHERE("USER_TABLE.LAST_NAME" + " = #{last}");
            WHERE("USER_TABLE.LOCATION" + " = #{location}");

        }}.toString();
    }

}
```

In the above mentioned `QueryBuilder`, how the **SQL query** parameters were able to get mapped to  "first" and "last" param values, defined in the *'userMapper' interface*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MyBatis** builds an [dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) for **mapper** like [Spring AOP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224465/use-of-proxies-in-spring-aop), for **MyBatis** is using [MapperProxyFactory](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/d74d0bd90be915a6fe18b6ab33c6e608606a3dd4/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/binding/MapperProxyFactory.java) to create the **proxy instance** [MapperProxy](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/19a831b0c7348a431286a4c36a6d72679f733047/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/binding/MapperProxy.java) with the **proxy interface**(`UserMapper`).

So when invoke the `getUserId`, `MapperProxy` will catch the **target method** and **parameters** by:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
```

this will invoke the correspond [MapperMethod](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/19a831b0c7348a431286a4c36a6d72679f733047/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/binding/MapperMethod.java) to execute the **sql** with **converted args to parameters** by:

```
Object param = method.convertArgsToSqlCommandParam(args);
result = sqlSession.selectOne(command.getName(), param);
```

Since `method.convertArgsToSqlCommandParam` actually will generated **named parameters** by **@Param** annotations.

and also need to replace **placeholder**(`#{first}`) to **ask** and with correspond parameters, after this it will create [BoundSql](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/d74d0bd90be915a6fe18b6ab33c6e608606a3dd4/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/mapping/BoundSql.java) that own the **raw sql** and **parameters**, these will hand to **jdbc dirver** to execute like we use the **jdbcTemplate** directly.

- [sqlSourceParser.parse(replacePlaceholder(sql), parameterType, new HashMap());](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/b9b50abb83c8e386fb9ce8012b907293531ec211/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/builder/annotation/ProviderSqlSource.java#L129)

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that `UserQueryBuilder` does not get parameters defines in `UserMapper` interface.

There are several components participating in query execution:

1. the client of the mapper
2. mapper interface
3. query builder
4. spring-mybatis library
5. mybatis library

The mapper interface purpose is:

1. to specify the query that would be used
2. to specify parameters that query require
3. to define actual java interface

Mapper may define the query directly using annotation like `@Select`, implicitly using the query defined in xml mapping or using the query builder via `@SelectProvider`. The purpose of the builder is the same as of `@Select` or xml mapping, namely to `provide the query text` to mapper.

The actual implementation of the mapper is provided by the `spring-mybatis`. That implementation is created dynamically based on the mapper class. The implementation works like this: when a method on the mapper is invoked it uses reflection to invoke appropriate methods (like `selectOne` or `selectList` based on the return type defined in the mapper method) on mybatis `SqlSession`. In order to do that it needs query text and parameters. Query text is taken from builder/annotation/xml. Parameters are available as parameters to mapper method invocation. Then `SqlSessoin` itself uses the query and parameters to execute the query using JDBC API.